# Getting all rows from database

Tags: php, array

i have an array string with id numbers
example: `$taxIds=array(9,13)`

how to fetch all record with this query??

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "Select * from `ath_webservice_sale` where `id`='$taxIds'";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I guess the "quick" way would be to use an IN clause in your mysql query so it would look as follows.

```
Select * from `ath_webservice_sale` where `id` IN '$taxIds'"
```

Now this will give you the information you need but it is not really the Magento Way.

You can use `$resource->getTableName('replace/this');` to get the table name when replacing `replace/this` with the appropriate information as set in your module's config.xml.

Secondly remember to escape the array when using this in your sql.

Answer (score 1):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model')->getCollection();
$collection->addIdFilter($taxIds);
```

Comment: Suggestion to use   `$collection->addFieldToFilter('id', array('in' => $ids));  instead of '$collection->addIdFilter($taxIds)'. Your answer will work whenever it have  the table have  any a model

Comment: No resault im using this:

Comment: $collection = Mage::getModel('orders/custommodel')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('id', array('in' => $taxIds));